# Pygame Menu won't change to level

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

My game opens up to a menu and whenever I select any of the options (Easy, Medium, Hard) it always opens the Easy level no matter what option I click. If someone could have a look over my code (mostly the option, menu, and main functions) and show me where I went wrong and how to fix it that would be greatly appreciated.

```
class Option:
    hovered = False
    def __init__(self, text, pos):
        self.text = text
        self.pos = pos
        self.set_rect()
        self.draw()
    def draw(self):
        self.set_rend()
        screen.blit(self.rend, self.rect)
    def set_rend(self):
        self.rend = menu_font.render(self.text, True, self.get_color())
    def get_color(self):
        if self.hovered:
            return (WHITE)
        else:
            return (GREY)
    def set_rect(self):
        self.set_rend()
        self.rect = self.rend.get_rect()
        self.rect.topleft = self.pos

options = [Option("Easy", (450, 205)), Option("Medium", (450, 305)),
           Option("Hard", (450, 405)), Option("Exit", (450, 505))]



levels = [[
    "WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW",
    "WF                                                             GW",
    "W                              P                                W",
    "W                                                               W",
    "WH                                                             IW",
    "WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW",
    ],
    [
    "WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW",
    "WF                                                             GW",
    "W                              P                                W",
    "W                      W                                        W",
    "W                       W                                       W",
    "W                        W                                      W",
    "W                         WW                                    W",
    "W                           W                                   W",
    "W                            W                                  W",
    "W                             W                                 W",
    "W                              W                                W",
    "W                                                               W",
    "W                                                               W",
    "W                                                               W",
    "W                                                               W",
    "WH                                                             IW",
    "WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW",
    ],
    [
    "WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW",
    "WF                                                             GW",
    "W                           W                                   W",
    "W                            W                                  W",
    "W                             W                                 W",
    "W                              W                                W",
    "W                               W                               W",
    "W                                W                              W",
    "W                                 W                             W",
    "W                                  W                            W",
    "W                                                               W",
    "W                                                               W",
    "W                                                               W",
    "W                                                               W",
    "W                                                               W",
    "W                              P                                W",
    "WH                                                             IW",
    "WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW",
    ]]

def load_level(level):
    walls = []
    players = []
    finishes = []
    x = y = 0
    for row in levels[level]:
        for col in row:
            if col == "W":
                walls.append(Wall((x, y)))
            if col == "P":
                players.append(Player((x, y)))
            if col == "F":
                finishes.append(Finish1((x, y)))
            if col == "G":
                finishes.append(Finish2((x, y)))
            if col == "H":
                finishes.append(Finish3((x, y)))
            if col == "I":
                finishes.append(Finish4((x, y)))
            x += 16
        y += 16
        x = 0
    return walls, players, finishes

walls, players, finishes = load_level(currentLevel)


def Menu():
    runnin = True
    while runnin:
        clock.tick(60)
        screen.fill(BLACK)
        mouseclick = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit(0)
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit(0)
        for option in options:
            if option.rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
                option.hovered = True
                if mouseclick[0] == 1:
                    if option.text == "Easy":
                        walls, players, finishes = load_level(0)
                        global currentlevel
                        currentlevel = 0
                        main()
                    elif option.text == "Medium":
                        walls, players, finishes = load_level(1)
                        currentlevel = 1
                        main()
                    elif option.text == "Hard":
                        walls, players, finishes = load_level(2)
                        currentlevel = 2
                        main()
                    else:
                        runnin = False
            else:
                option.hovered = False
            option.draw()
        pygame.display.update()
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit(0)

def main():
    pygame.display.update()
    rand = random.randint(1, 4)
    running = True
    while running:
        for option in options:
            if option.rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
                option.hovered = True
            else:
                option.hovered = False
            option.draw()
        # Move the player if an arrow key is pressed
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if total_seconds > 0:
            if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
                player.move(-2, 0)
            if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
                player.move(2, 0)
            if key[pygame.K_UP]:
                player.move(0, -2)
            if key[pygame.K_DOWN]:
                player.move(0, 2)

        for wall in walls:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (WHITE), wall.rect)
        for player in players:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (YELLOW), player.rect)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (GREEN), Finish1.rect)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (GREEN), Finish2.rect)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (GREEN), Finish3.rect)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (GREEN), Finish4.rect)

        if rand == 1:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (RED), Finish1.rect)
        elif rand == 2:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (RED), Finish2.rect)
        elif rand == 3:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (RED), Finish3.rect)
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (RED), Finish4.rect)
        pygame.display.flip()
Menu()
```

Comment: Please give a [mcve], it's a bit much to ask people to trawl through all of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your new edited example isn't working because `menu_font` is no longer defined. Nevertheless your problem is caused by this line

```
walls, players, finishes = load_level(currentLevel)
```

It is always executed, `currentLevel` is set to `0` at the beginning, therefore your level is set to easy. In your `Menu()` function you overwrite the variables `walls`, `players`, `finishes` locally (i.e. in your function). Your function `main()` tries to access the the global variables. You can fix that simply by using by changing the `if option.text` block and commenting out the first `load_level` call, or better by passing the variables to your main function.

```
                if option.text == "Easy":
                    walls, players, finishes = load_level(0)
                    global currentlevel, walls, players, finishes
                    currentlevel = 0
                    main()
                elif option.text == "Medium":
                    walls, players, finishes = load_level(1)
                    global currentlevel, walls, players, finishes
                    currentlevel = 1
                    main()
                elif option.text == "Hard":
                    walls, players, finishes = load_level(2)
                    global currentlevel, walls, players, finishes
                    currentlevel = 2
                    main()
                else:
                    runnin = False
```

alternatively:

```
            if option.text == "Easy":
                walls, players, finishes = load_level(0)
                currentlevel = 0
                main(walls, players, finishes, currentlevel)
-------------
def main(walls, players, finishes, currentlevel):
[put your old code here]
```